# How to distribute a custom WinPE disk

Tags: windows, windows-pe, distribution, development, distro

I'm looking into creating a WinPE disk that runs a custom cleanup utility that can be distributed to clients.

I'm hoping to get some clarity on how companies legally distribute custom WinPE disks without getting heat from MS.

I've been told that if the PE disk is built on the clients end using a "custom packager" instead of being distributed as a whole then it is acceptable. If this is true where do the MS files come from? Does MS host them somewhere that can be downloaded?

Does any one version of WinPE have different licensing terms that allow this sort of distribution?